# MS Excel | Return Cell reference value if MAX value is used

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have data in column C and E. The values in both these columns is random. I'm looking for the highest value to be returned in column I. So I have =MAX in column I.
I would like column J to return which winning column this was taken from. So my labels for column C & E are in listed in C3 & E3.
What formula can I use to return these?

My Random data is in
Col C7
Col E7

Col  Labels are
Col C3
Col E3

My winning selection is in
I7

Would like The data in Col J7 to be returned from either C3 or E3 based on the value in I7.

Can you help?

Comment: How is your current MAX function written? Are all your values in C & E put together distinct?Can there be repeating MAX value in Col C as well as E? May be a sample screenshot could help solve your query.

Comment: http://prnt.sc/e26ke8

Comment: What you wish to return in Col J? Should it simply be Column Name say Col C or Col E based on where the MAX value for that row is? And what if values in Col C & E are equal, there's a tie?

Comment: The returned value in J7 should be either "Desktop" or "Mobile" based on where the value is picked up from.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use MATCH function to check where match exists and based on the IF criteria return either "Desktop" or "Mobile" in Column I. This solution shall not factor in Tie case. 
In I7 Put

```
=MAX(C7,E7)
```

In J7 put

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(I7,C7,0)),"Mobile","Desktop")
```

and drag it down.

[image]

And just in case you wish to factor in Tie and return it as "Tie" in Col J, put the following formula in I7 and drag it down

```
=IF(AND(EXACT(I7,C7),EXACT(I7,E7)),"Tie",IF(EXACT(I7,C7),"Desktop","Mobile"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In I7, your formula should be:

```
=MAX(C7,E7)
```

And in J7, your formula should be:

```
=IF(C7>E7,$B$4,IF(C7<E7,$E$4,"Equal"))
```

This will output "Test A" if C is greater than E, "Test B" if E is greater than C, and "Equal" otherwise.